# PHP. Remove URL and URL encode

Tags: php

How could I turn this string:

```
//twitter.com/home?status=Bob Muno %7C via @MyUnknownWebsite https://dev.MyUnknownWebsite.com/people/bob_muno
```

into

```
Bob Muno | via @MyUnknownWebsite https://dev.MyUnknownWebsite.com/people/bob_muno
```

Comment: If %7C will always be there, this wouldn't be too hard with regex.

Comment: Can you ask a real question? This looks like an excerpt from one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
    $original="//twitter.com/home?status=Bob Muno %7C via @MyUnknownWebsite https://dev.MyUnknownWebsite.com/people/bob_muno";
    $parts=explode("=",$original);
    echo urldecode($parts[1]); // decoding url for %7C -> |
?>
```

This should work.